# Unable to record https website in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

1) Trying to record secure website.
2) Error is displaying -- can't record secure website.

Please help to record and send me the steps and settings how to record secure script in JMeter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you recording? Do you use a HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder combined with a Recording Controller? I never had problems using these elements even on secured websites.

Answer (score 6):

In order to record a secured (https) web application, you need to add the Apache Jmeter Security Certificate into your browser where you're recording.

For example, if you're recording through Mozila Firefox. Follow, the below setps:

```
-Navigate to Tools >> Options >> Advanced >> Certificates >> View Certificates >> Authorities

-Click on import and map to Bin directory of your Apache Jmeter installation. 

-Select the ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt file and you're done.
```

Comment: An important safety tip. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all clean all your browsing history, cookies, cache, content licenses, etc.
2. Second: make sure that in your browser proxy configuration "Use proxy for all protocols" is selected

   [image: Proxy all protocols]
3. You can quickly get "good" JMeter recording configuration by using [Template](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#template) feature - it is available from JMeter's Main Menu: File -> Templates -> Recording -> Create (in this case proxy will bind to port 8888)
4. When you open website you're trying to record first time - accept JMeter's self-signed certificate. It is some form of [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) proxy which allows decrypting secure traffic in order to be able to record it.

See [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) article for more detailed explanation and workarounds for common issues.